# Upload file in selenium, python

Tags: selenium

I ask  for help in solving my problem. Sorry for any mistakes but this is the first time I ask a question. I have a problem with uploading the file in selenium. I was looking for solutions to my problem but I haven't found it.

This is my html code:

```
<div id="scans-attachments__file__passport-container" class="file-uploader">
    <input type="hidden" name="scans[attachments__file__passport]" value="" id="scans-attachments__file__passport">
    <div class="filepond--root filepond--hopper" data-style-button-remove-item-position="left" data-style-button-process-item-position="right" data-style-load-indicator-position="right" data-style-progress-indicator-position="right" data-style-button-remove-item-align="false" style="height: 76px;">
        <input class="filepond--browser" type="file" id="filepond--browser-2ybdvwfwp" name="filepond">
    </div>
</div>
```

i try to do it:

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element(By.ID, "filepond--browser-2ybdvwfwp").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/image.jpg")
```

I get:

```
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"Unable to locate element: [id=\\"filepond\\"]...ntent/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:393:5\\nelement.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:299:16\\n"}}'}
```

I have you to thank for your help

Comment: Interesting! I can see in error message it is considering `filepond` as `id` I don't know why the remaining value is truncated.  Please try `find_element(By.NAME, "filepond")`

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your helpful answer. There is a new problem - on this page there is another imput type="file" name="filepond" and  the file is uploaded but for this field, now I try to use xpath but I get: 
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"element not interactable","message":"Element <div class=\\"filepond--drop...sChild.jsm:485:24\\nreceiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:148:31\\n"}}'}
I will try with other xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message...

```
"error":"no such element","message":"Unable to locate element: [id=\\"filepond\\"]
```

...says the `id = filepond` is not available on DOM. I am not sure why the remaining value is truncated. Please try with below element,

```
find_element(By.NAME, "filepond")
```